# Can't apt-get update, and unmet dependencies libjpeg8, and System error with ubuntu desktop

Tags: apt, 16.04

I cant install anything on ubuntu and I have system error on top line (this red circle with white line) and when i want to fix this using update I get:

```
Can't install 'ubuntu-desktop'
It was impossible to install a required package. Please report this as a bug using 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
```

when I try to install something I always get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libjpeg8 : Depends: libjpeg-turbo8 (>= 1.1.90+svn722-1ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
     libjpeg8-dev : Depends: libjpeg8 (= 8d-1+deb7u1) but 8c-2ubuntu8 is to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and when i type `sudo apt-get update` I get:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

When I type `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libjpeg-turbo8
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libjpeg8
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libjpeg8
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
73 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/138 kB of archives.
After this operation, 267 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libjpeg8
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] n
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
```

When I choose install without verification(y) i get:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8', which is also in package libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 1.4.2-0ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code
```

I'm using Xenial 16.04 amd64 Ubuntu

Thanks for help ;)

Comment: You may have to use `aptitude`. See my answer here: [How to install/upgrade to the latest version of Poppler/`pdftoppm` (version 22.11.0 at the time of this writing) on Linux Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74313286/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation. The libjpeg8 package from the Ubuntu repositories is clashing with a package with the same name from the Debian repositories. Here's the output from apt-cache which shows the clashing packages:

```
apt-cache show libjpeg8
Package: libjpeg8
Version: 8d-1+deb7u1
Installed-Size: 287
Maintainer: Bill Allombert <ballombe@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7)
Pre-Depends: multiarch-support
Description-en: Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library
 The Independent JPEG Group's JPEG library is a library for handling
 JPEG files.
 .
 This package contains the shared library.
Description-md5: 4ca10faa4517c5d362c9d51d75d7a85c
Multi-Arch: same
Tag: implemented-in::c, role::shared-lib
Section: libs
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/libj/libjpeg8/libjpeg8_8d-1+deb7u1_amd64.deb
Size: 137708
MD5sum: 93e9da26d8ebe1a6c09e15b4276ccce7
SHA1: aff2208366f95d286da91b81d27d65e834d0d692
SHA256: 70dee072e3d06d9977fc1c495d4336991e16a91d43ce9678f4f24ae719b780c5

Package: libjpeg8
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 26
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: libjpeg8-empty
Version: 8c-2ubuntu8
Depends: libjpeg-turbo8 (>= 1.1.90+svn722-1ubuntu6)
Filename: pool/main/libj/libjpeg8-empty/libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu8_amd64.deb
Size: 2194
MD5sum: e0f16286dd787b951ffa953987fdf6a7
SHA1: 50f0a11ba80717e17b8485567ee1be76b744ce8f
SHA256: baaecbc8e7ef55fc1887365721a7771f7d533fabca38fca878668b9c8f7ee13f
Description-en: Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
 libjpeg8 dependency package, depending on libjpeg-turbo8.
Description-md5: c291a11286499ba1bdfddf14d8af677b
Multi-Arch: same
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 5y
Task: virt-host, ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-usb, print-server, tomcat-server, kubuntu-desktop, edubuntu-desktop, edubuntu-usb, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-frontend, mythbuntu-desktop, mythbuntu-backend-slave, mythbuntu-backend-master, lubuntu-core, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntu-gnome-desktop, ubuntu-sdk-libs, ubuntu-touch, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-mate-cloudtop
```

Check your Apt sources file and if you see a Debian repository mentioned there, comment it out and try updating again.

Open up a terminal and run the following commands:

```
# Create a backup of the original file
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bu
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Look for the following line:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
```

Comment it out by adding a hash (#) in the beginning so that it becomes:

```
# deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
```

Save the file by pressing CTRL-O and then exit by pressing CTRL+X.

Run the update/upgrade process again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```